# wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I'm encountering this error after creating a brand new partition.

What I did:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6E6B69EE-CD95-47E3-94A0-AA9190306D40

# fdisk /dev/sdb
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-7814037133, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-7814037133, default 7814037133): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 3.7 TiB.
Partition #1 contains a ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: n

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6E6B69EE-CD95-47E3-94A0-AA9190306D40

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814037133 7814035086  3.7T Linux filesystem

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

After that, this was the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6E6B69EE-CD95-47E3-94A0-AA9190306D40

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814037133 7814035086  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

That's the error I get when mounting:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/data_storage/
mount: /mnt/data_storage: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

It's worth noting that all those operation were executed on the same machine, and that machine is an aarch64 with Ubuntu 18.04.1.

The same operations executed on an x64 Ubuntu 18.04 computer resulted in a correct ext4 partition which I was able to mount and read/write.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Did you create the file system? For example `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`...

Comment: It's usually easier to use `gparted` to do all the steps automatically, it even does a `wipefs` before formatting to avoid any old problems

Comment: @lx07 I didn't. I should try to.

Comment: @Xen2050 I used GParted the first time. I was on my Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop x64, I deleted all partitions, created a new partition table and an ext4 partition. I was able to mount the partition and write my data, but after connecting the disk to my aarch64 device (a Pine64 equipped with ARMBian) that error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's additional parameter it's work in my case with following command:

> $sudo mount -t [file-system]-o nouuid /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mountpoint